# Get preprocessed C code altogether with library implementation

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I use *nix/gcc. I am beginner in C so this may be an easy question. Let's say I have a file main.c with the following content:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Hello World.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Now what I want to get is one file which contains all code after preprocessing and all library implementation code (for inspection purpose). Now, if I run

```
gcc -E main.c >> full.c
```

I do get bunch of code, but there are only data types and function prototypes. Is it possible somehow to also get implementation of all functions, so that I can see whole code in one place.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by implementation of all functions.  The only thing you are going to get is the contents of the file stdio.h along with the contents of this file which is just a simple main with a couple of lines of source.  What is it that you are expecting?

Comment: My code uses printf. What I see in full.c is only prototype of printf (among other things). There is no source code of printf. If I look at glibc and find printf function there, I can see its source code implementation, but not in full.c. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

The C Preprocessor just does text manipulation.  In this case what it will do is to generate an output file that will contain the contents of the include file stdio.h along with the couple of lines of your main program.

It will not contain the stdio.h function implementations as that source is in some other files which are not provided in source code format with gcc.

So if you want the implementation you will need to find the gcc Standard C library source code which I expect is on the web some place.

However if you want to understand the Standard C library you should start with Plaughers books on the Standard C library or something similar which provides implementation as well as annotations and notes about what is done and why.

Comment: OK I think I understand now. Let's say I have stdio implementation, can You tell me what gcc command (vaguely) can I use to link those together.